# How to define a controller in Component Driven Architecture using ui-router?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, signature

How to define a controller in component driven architecture using Ui-Router?

States are included in App.js and Controllers are defined in individual component folders.

```
$stateProvider.state('route1', {
    url:'/route1',
    views: {
      "ViewA": {
        templateUrl: 'View.html',
        controller: 'ViewController'
      }
    }
  })
```

---

```
(function(myApp) {

var ViewController = function($scope) {
    $scope.message='AngularJS'
};

ViewController.$inject = ['$scope','$http'];
myApp.controller('ViewController', ViewController);}(angular.module('myApp')));
```

---

```
<div ng-controller="ViewController" ><label> {{message}}</label>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you mean by "Component Driven Architecture" the fact that your application has independent modules in individual component folders,

**1. Create your component modules in their respective folders and attach the controllers to them**

You can either do this if both the module and the controller is in the same file:

```
angular.module('myComponent', []).controller(function($scope) {
    //Code here
});
```

Or you can get the reference to your module like this if the controller is in another file:

```
angular.module('myComponent').controller(function($scope) {
        //Code here
    });
```

**2. Inject your components in to your main module:**

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myComponent'])
```

This way your component controllers become available in your main module and `$stateProvider` configuration.

---

Also note that you don't have to use `ng-controller` in your `View.html`. That is automatically done when you say `controller: 'ViewController'` when changing state.

Comment: Great !!! but if not using UI - Router then what is the controller representation? @Charlie H

Comment: You can still define controllers and modules in this manner on a static html page. There you will have to use `ng-controller` as needed. You can also share services and other providers between modules if the modules are correctly injected.